# Can we schedule JMeter to run for an hour for specific number of users?

Tags: jmeter

If we want to execute the script for an hour for 5k users, which thread group will fit best? How do I make sure that only 5k users will be injected in whole 1 hour?

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can, this can be implemented using any Thread Group derivative, i.e.

1. Normal JMeter [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group):

   [image: JMeter Thread Group]
2. [Concurrency Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-load-testing-scenarios-jmeter-part-4-stepping-thread-group-and-concurrency-thread)

   [image: Concurrency Thread GRoup]
3. [Ultimate Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/)

   [image: Ultimate Thread Group]

By default you have only option #1, other Thread Groups can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

Comment: It's injecting more than 5000 threads and tests runs for double duration. By that way, -1 seems wrong, once plan is saved, field gets blank